# Shell scripting and sqlite3

Tags: python, shell, sqlite

Scenario:
I am trying out a small shell scripting program.

In this program- I am trying to query a database with 2 tables. and trying to get a yes or no answer.

The `etag = md5sum` that I fetch from the file using a python script.

```
echo 'select a.hash,b.hashuser, case when a.hash=b.hashuser then "No!" else "yes!" end from tempo b, hashes a where a.hash=b.hashuser and b.hashuser='$etag''
```

When I try to print it on my screen it shows it clearly that etag as the md5sum

But, If I try to query it on my database and try to fetch the result.  using the script given below

```
sqlite3 hashez.db 'select a.hash,b.hashuser, case when a.hash=b.hashuser then "No!" else "yes!" end from tempo b, hashes a where a.hash=b.hashuser and b.hashuser='$etag''
```

This is the error that I get.

```
 Error: unrecognized token: "579f0b61cf958a0eea2f60906e6a04a4"
```

After googling a little bit, this the solution I found from this [link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/146376-execution-problem-shell-script.html)

Then I changed it to `${#etag}`

```
echo 'select a.hash,b.hashuser, case when a.hash=b.hashuser then "No!" else "yes!" end from tempo b, hashes a where a.hash=b.hashuser and b.hashuser='${#etag}''
```

The error that I get now is

```
select a.hash,b.hashuser, case when a.hash=b.hashuser then "No!" else "yes!" end from tempo b, hashes a where a.hash=b.hashuser and **b.hashuser=32**
```

Why is b.hashuser=32. is my first question.

Second problem:

When I try to query the database using the above function:

```
sqlite3 hashez.db 'select a.hash,b.hashuser, case when a.hash=b.hashuser then "No!" else "yes!" end from tempo b, hashes a where a.hash=b.hashuser and b.hashuser='${#etag}''
```

I got no reply back.

- Is my query wrong. , If yes, why am I getting an answer when I query it directly on the database?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're goofing on your quotes.

```
somecmd 'SELECT ... "'"$etag"'", ...'
```

Note the double quotes inside the single quotes, as well as around the parameter substitution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It works!
Just one more question.
As I understand - "$blah" --> will throw it as a character.
But '$blah' will throw it the value within the variable

Am I correct?

Comment: No. Single quotes inhibit parameter substitution, which is why you close them first and then open double quotes, and then do it backwards after.